# C++ avoiding code duplication for const and non-const visitation

Tags: c++, const-correctness, visitor-pattern

I have a class that should call a visitor method for every member variable. Something like this:

```
class A{
    int a, b, c;

public:
    void accept(Visitor &visitor){
        visitor.visit(a);
        visitor.visit(b);
        visitor.visit(c);
    }
};
```

How can I get `void accept() const` method with the same code without code duplication?

The obvious solution with the duplication is to add a method:

```
void accept(Visitor &visitor) const {
    visitor.visit(a);
    visitor.visit(b);
    visitor.visit(c);
}
```

That method has exactly the meaning I want, but I would like to avoid the code duplication. The reason to have both methods is to be able to read the variables by a 'reading' visitor and having the `accept` method nicely `const`. Then the non-const `accept` would be possible to use for 'writing/updating' visitors.

Comment: Where does the code duplication take place. Not enough info.

Comment: What is the signature of `visit`? If it's const, then there's no need for a non-const `accept`. If it's not, then this `accept` can't be const.

Comment: Can't you just put a `const` on the current `accept` method?  Why would you need a non-const version of accept?

Comment: @Beta: It's possible that `visit()` is overloaded for `const` and non-`const`.

Comment: @Beta: `Visitor::visit` could be overloaded on `const int&` vs. `int&` parameter, with the latter potentially modifying the thing visited. Not sure if that's *wise*, but the questioner's current, duplicated code permits it.

Comment: @Oli, but there's a big difference between `accept(...) const` and `accept(const Visitor&)`.  With a non-const Visitor, we would call the non-const `Visitor::visit()` - regardless of whether `accept()` is const or non-const.

Comment: @Tim: I was thinking more along the lines of `Visitor::visit(const int &)` and `Visitor::visit(int &)`.

Comment: @Oli and @Steve - good point, but ew.  I really hope `Visitor`'s not like that.

Comment: It isn't code duplication if the functions call different overload of visit. If they were called Visitor.read and Visitor.update, we wouldn't consider this. Why bother with the fact that they happen to have the same name?

Comment: @Bo: Even if the methods have different names, I would consider that a code duplication.

Comment: @Bo: my concern is that some styles prefer not to pass by non-const reference, especially with built-in types, and especially with function names that don't explicitly suggest modification. Which means that some programmers will be surprised when `visit(a)` modifies `this->a` rather than passing it by value. I can live with it, especially since it allows simple code-sharing for what might be several such visitor functions. Naming the functions differently could still work if the template takes an additional member-function-pointer template argument, and might help some readers, so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a class static template helper function that will deduce the constness based on the type of the `this` pointer you provide to it. Like this:

```
class A{
    int a, b, c;

public:

    void accept(Visitor &visitor){
        acceptImpl(*this, visitor);
    }
    void accept(Visitor &visitor) const{
        acceptImpl(*this, visitor);
    }

private:
    template<typename t_A>
    static void acceptImpl(t_A& aObj, Visitor &visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(aObj.a);
        visitor.visit(aObj.b);
        visitor.visit(aObj.c);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Template helper:

```
class A{
    int a, b, c;

private:
    template <typename T>
    static void do_visiting(T &self, Visitor &visitor) {
        visitor.visit(self.a);
        visitor.visit(self.b);
        visitor.visit(self.c);
    }
public:
    void accept(Visitor &visitor) {
        do_visiting(*this, visitor); // calls do_visiting<A>
    }
    void accept(Visitor &visitor) const {
        do_visiting(*this, visitor); // calls do_visiting<const A>
    }
};
```